# Joining three tables where the term is an exclusion

Tags: mysql

I have a query that involves 3 tables.  The table "project" contains the records I want to retrieve.

3 tables: 
 
**project**

**participants:**
 
id
 
project_id (refers  to id of table 1)
 
usertable_id    (refers to is of table 3)

**usertable:**
 
id
 
lastname
 
user_type (either "active" or "inactive")

I want to retrieve all the projects (table 1) where the participants (table 2) are NOT of  user_type = 'inactive' (table 3)

What is the correct query to join these three tables so that only these projects are retrieved?

Comment: show the table structure in a more readable way

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from projects p 
left join participants ps on ps.project_id = p.id 
left join usertable u on ps.usertable_id = u.id 
where u.user_type <> 'inactive'
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a simple join query with your where filter

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM project p
LEFT JOIN participants pr ON(p.id = pr.project_id)
LEFT JOIN usertable  u ON(u.id=pr.usertable_id )
WHERE u.user_type <> 'inactive'
```

**Edit from comments**

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM project p
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT 1
 FROM participants pr
JOIN usertable  u ON(u.id=pr.usertable_id )
WHERE u.user_type = 'inactive'
AND  pr.project_id= p.id 
)
```

Comment: I tried this and it still gave me records where the participants associated with that project were inactive.  COuld the reason be that there are multiple participants for each project?  Does the above query take that into account?

Comment: @user2557039 this query will give you the projects whose participants are not inactive no matter there are multiple participants,if you need that all the participants of a project even a single participant  should not be inactive then let me know i will update my answer accordingly

Comment: Yes I mean only projects where EVERONE is active (or no one is inactive).  I knoiw that soudns confusing :-)